# Build a Pdf document with merge field from a record

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I have tried to do this for few days, now I need your help. When in my org an user save a Lead a Pdf document have to be created automaticly. The Pdf have a template and the fields from the saved lead need to be put in that document in few blank spaces.
Now I'm using a VF page that render my lead page as a Pdf a custom controller and an helper class but It's not working because I'm not able to pass the fields between the saved Lead and the VF page.
Someone could give me a tip. Every Tips are very appreciated

Sorry I put the code below:
the vf page rendered as Pdf

```
    <apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="dataController"  renderAs="pdf">   
<apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.stannah}"  style="margin-left:250px; margin-top:40px;"/> 
  <br/>
  <br/>  
  <h2>Gentile <apex:outputText value=" {!name}"/></h2>
  <br/>
  Ci risulta che lei lavora presso <apex:outputText value=" {!company}"/><br/>
  <br/> 
  Siamo riusciti a creare il file pdf con i suoi dati<br/>
  Grazie per aver richiesto informazioni per i nostri prodotti<br/>
  <br/>
<apex:image id="theImage2" value="{!$Resource.num_verde}"  style="margin-left:245px; margin-top:40px;"/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Cordiali saluti<br/>
  Lo staff di Stannah  
</apex:page>
```

this is the controller extension

```
global class dataController {
    global static String nn1;
    global static String cc2;

  public String name {get; set;}
  public String company {get; set;}

  public Lead ld{get;set;}  

     private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

   public dataController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
       this.stdController = stdController;
       this.ld = (Lead)stdController.getrecord();
       getMydata();
   }

   public void getMydata() {
       name=nn1;
       company=cc2;
       System.debug('7name: '+name);
       System.debug('8company: '+Company);
   }
}
```

This is the help class. I use this with a process builder when a lead is created process builder fired the invocable method that have to create the pdf page and put it in a document

```
public class PdfLead {

@InvocableMethod(label='PDF' description='creo dei pdf')   
public static list<String> pagePdf(){
    System.debug('passo 1');

    Lead l=[select id, firstName, company from lead order by CreatedDate desc limit 1];
      System.debug('1name: '+l.FirstName);
      System.debug('2company: '+l.Company);

     dataController.nn1 = l.FirstName;
     dataController.cc2 = l.Company;
     System.debug('3name: '+dataController.nn1);
     System.debug('4company: '+ dataController.cc2);
     Blob b;

     PageReference pdf = Page.PageOfLead;
    //pdf.getParameters().put('id', ld.Id);
    pdf.setRedirect(true);
    Blob body;

    try{
    // returns the output of the page as a PDF
    body = pdf.getContent();
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
      body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
        System.debug(e);
        //10:59:06:171 USER_DEBUG [18]|DEBUG|System.VisualforceException: 
        //system.security.NoDataFoundException: Unable to retrieve object
    }

     /*generatePdf2 gp = new generatePdf2();
     b = gp.pagePdf2();   
     System.debug('5Dimensione: '+b.size());*/

     document d = new document(); 
        d.folderid='00lU00000018TxaIAE';
        d.Name = l.FirstName; 
        d.Body = b; 
        d.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
        d.Type = 'pdf';

    insert d;
    return null;
}
```

Now we are trying to pass only lead Name and Company to the Vf page rendered as Pdf, but it's not working. Sorry if i don't put the code before.

Comment: Are you able to share what you already have done?

Comment: Request you to share your code if possible

Comment: Please note code dumps in the comments are frowned upon. Please [edit] your post with any such content.

Comment: I edit the post sorry if I didn't post the code before

Answer (score 1):

For your `Visualforce`, you don't even need an extension. You can merge in fields from the standard controller. Here is a simple demonstration:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <div>
        Name: <apex:outputField value="{!Lead.Name}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Company: <apex:outputField value="{!Lead.Company}" />
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

It might not solve the root issue but it will at least simplify your code. Don't use `Apex` unless you have to.

Comment: I know but in this way I'm not be able to generate a pdf from that lead

Comment: How automatic does it have to be? I have done something like this using a standard controller and calling the PDF Page from a button.  That would eliminate the need to for the Apex passing values back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to pass those values through using some static values in the controller.  You have the lead record in the controller, why not just display those values. You may need to requery for the fields, but probably not. Just change your visualforce page to display {!ld.name}.